# Code Coverage tool for BlackBerry

Tags: testing, blackberry, code-coverage, metrics, java-me

I'm looking for a [code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) tool that I can use with a BlackBerry application. I'm using J2ME-Unit for Unit Testing and I want to see how much of my code is being covered by my tests.

I've tried using [Cobertura for J2ME](http://www.cobertura4j2me.org/) but after days of wrestling with it I failed to get any results from it. (I believe that the instrumentation is un-done by the RAPC compilation). And despite [this message](http://blog.dreameffect.org/2008/09/25/cobertura-for-j2me-is-not-dead/), the project seems to be dead.

I've looked at [JInjector](http://code.google.com/p/jinjector/) but the project seems *very* incomplete. There is little (if any) documentation and although it *claims* to be able to work with BlackBerry projects, I haven't seen any places where it *has* been used for that purpose. I've played with the project quite a bit but to no avail.

I've also tried the "Coverage" view in the BlackBerry JDE, even though I use Eclipse for development. The view stays permanently blank, regardless of clicking "Refresh" and running the application from the JDE.

I've looked at [most of the tools on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329/what-is-your-favourite-code-coverage-tools-free-and-non-free), but they won't work with J2ME/BlackBerry projects.

**Has anyone had any success with any code coverage tools on the BlackBerry?** If so, what tools have you used? How have you used them?

If anyone *has* managed to get JInjector or Cobertura for J2ME to work with a BlackBerry project, what did you have to do to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for Coberatura or JInjector, because I don't know how they collect test coverage probe data.

What is
critical is how this data is captured (does it need Java runtime support only available in standard Java VMs?) and how it is exported to the test coverage display/report generation tools.

Our [SD Java Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html) tool instruments your source code; at runtime this produces an array of native Java booleans representing the coverage data, without need for any special VM support.  Normally, this array is exported directly to a file, used by the test coverage display mechanism, by a TCVDump method provided with the test coverage tool, as your application exits.

Java (and other programming langauges used) in embedded systems often requires custom methods to extract the test coverage data.  You might need to code a special dump procedure (in Java) to write out that boolean array to an accessible place.   Our experience with building such custom dump procedures is that they are generally pretty simple (a few dozen lines); the real trick is deciding how/where to put the data, so that it can be easily moved to the target file.  Mostly this is just a peculiar pair of copies, the first of which copies the boolean array to some staging location, and the second which writes the staged data into the destination file. (The standard TCVdump method is provided in source form to enable this kind of customization).

While I haven't specifically looked at BlackBerry, if you can write the data anywhere, you can pretty much be assured you can achieve this.   We've had success with other embedded hand-set systems, such as Symbian, doing this.

If you want a complete overview of how to generally instrument code for test coverage following this strategy, see this paper: [Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages Made Easy](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I was actively involved with JInjector while working at Google. We were able to use it to successfully obtain code coverage for Blackberry applications. The application lifecycle for Balckberry apps is less predictable than J2ME and we found we had to tweak the application code to ensure the coverage data was gathered. I didn't personally work on the blackberry apps, several other engineers did. I'd hoped we'd create an example blackberry application and make it available on the jinjector site, but events and life got in the way.

If you would be willing to provide a sample blackberry apps with some unit tests, I'd be willing to spend a few hours trying to help you get the code coverage working. I'm not actively working with either J2ME or Blackberry (I'm currently working on Android apps when I have time to experiment with mobile) so I'm quite rusty. I have a day job that doesn't involve much mobile test automation, however I continue to work on ways to improve the test automation for mobile apps e.g. http://code.google.com/p/mwta/downloads/list for Android Test Automation.

I'm julianharty at gmail.com

Comment: Thanks Julian, but this is mostly irrelevant to me now; I've since switched projects (though the BlackBerry application I was working on here was a big success). ;-)